# mysql docker container start with a fixed ip

Tags: mysql, docker

hi I have a mysql container running as a service, and for other services connect it with a jdbc url, with a ip:port.

and for sometimes the server needs to reboot. and the ip addr of mysql container will change, for every service needs to connect to mysql, the jdbc url needs to be modified.

is there a way to 'docker start' a container with a fixed ip address?

I've tried --ip but it's not working

docker version 1.11.2

Comment: are you using docker compose ?

Comment: so... are you suggesting use link?

Comment: yes. that's the right way.

Comment: @atv cool, I'm just asking if there is another way to solve this problem as a backup plan

Answer (score 3):

You can preset an IP to a container, but this must be done when you create the container (in the `docker run`).

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

To preset an IP to a container you ahve to add the switch `--ip="desired_ip_here"` in the `docker run`

Also you can use tools like [supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/) to manage you processes and restart services without stopping the container.

Comment: Do not add links. Cite the content because the answer is useless if the link is down..